# UML Class Diagram Android

Tags: android, uml, class-diagram

i want to make a Class Diagram from my Android app but I've never worked with UML in android so i have some stupid question.
Should I include all activities and classes or only class like DB_manage, preferences, etc. ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can include whatever you want (or whatever your requirements dictate you include). There is no official standard with respect to Android development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activity,Fragnment, etc, it is just a system ui containers not related to your logic. You should include entities such as MVP (MVVM) interfaces, implemented by activity, fragment because it show your logic and when UI is supposed to do. Placing everything in activity is a bad practice)

Comment: Thank you very much :) quick reply and a clear answer.